# get album id when uploading photo to picasa

Tags: android, picasa

I write an android application to upload a photo to a specific album. Let's say that I have an album name "school" already created. However, the picasa rest api (https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userID/albumid/albumID), expects album id.

Do I need to query all albums and match the albumid with the given name before posting a new photo in that album? I hesitate to maintain the album id locally in the phone since the album name may be changed from desktop web browser.

Answer (score 0):

"Album ID" is not a term used anywhere that I know of at the Picasa Web Albums site.
Do they want the URL to the web album?

and album url remains the same even if you change the name of the album.

so you can either save the album url with ur application(that will not change).

or iterate over the all albums. 
This is how a url may look like after creating an album with the API

`https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/here_is_ur_user_id/albumid/here_is_ur_album_id`

let me know if i can help more?

Thanks